# Centering left floated <li> tags inside of a container

Tags: html, css

I have a container that contains:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

As in here: http://sneakyrascal.com/gmat/conv/select-plan.html 
And the CSS for the `<li>` is set to the left so they can be in one line. If I remove one `<li>` then it will add an empty space to the right. like this one: http://sneakyrascal.com/gmat/conv/select-plan-2.html 
When I remove a `<li>` I want the other ones to be centered rather than being floated to the left. But I can't remove the `float:left` now that they need to be in one order. How can I get around it? I tried `margin: auto;` for `<ul>` but it didn't work.

Comment: The `display: inline-block` part of @Faust's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're absolutely constrained to using floats to achieve this, then you'll need some way to compute what the width of the container *should* be given the number of elements, and somehow apply it to the container directly. Then margin:auto should work fine.

Why? Because when you float the items, the container no longer uses them to calculate its width.

As is, it appears you are applying `width: 1050px` directly to the container. You might want to remove this style declaration from the stylesheet, and then (if you can) dynamically insert a class-name like columns-4 or columns-5 (depending on the count) to the container, then style each class with the appropriate width.

If, however, you can use other layout methods, then you have a couple of better options:

Apply `display:inline-block` on the lis, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/HPeAK/

Notes: 
1) ie6 won't apply `display:inline-block` to elements that are native blocks, like `<li>`, so if IE6 support is essential (yuck!), you would need to have a span inside that item and apply `display:inline-block` there.

2) inline-block will introduce white-spaces where they exist in the source because they are treated as inline elements.

**OR:**

Apply display:table on the container or ul, and display:table-cell on the `<li>`s,  like here: http://jsfiddle.net/3efZJ/

Comment: Actually, you can apply `inline-block` in IE6, all you need is to add `display:inline;zoom:1;` for IE in conditional comments for the block-level element where you want the `inline-block` behavior to be.

Comment: I like your solution and it worked in all the browsers but webkit ones, I know it's an issue related to my CSS in other lines. however I used jQuery solution from a good friend, you can check it here: http://sneakyrascal.com/gmat/conv/select-plan-3.html

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you set your UL to have `display: table`, `margin: 0 auto` will work on that and centre it. The alternative is set the UL to `display: inline-block` and use `text-align: center` on the container div to position it. With both of these though you are going to see problems with IE7 and below. It doesn't support `display: table` outright and `display: inline-block` only works on elements which are naturally inline, of which UL isn't.

Comment: Hi Chris, that's a great solution but my client needs this to work in IE7 as well.

Comment: A hack might be to place the UL inside another container, a new span. So your format would be div#container > span > ul. display inline-block on the span (which is valid) and then text-align: center on the div#container. **However**, this isn't valid HTML, as UL's should not be placed inside spans. I can't test in IE7 as I don't have it available I'm afraid but you may find it works, definitely no guarantees though.

Answer (score 1):

Make your container `overflow: hidden`:

```
.select-plan #container {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1050px;
}
```

Set the list as having `float: left; left: 50%; position: relative; margin: 0 auto` like so:

```
.select-plan #container ul {
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Give your list items `right: 50%` like so

```
.select-plan #container ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #666666;
    float: left;
    height: 418px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 187px;
    right: 50%;
}
```

This hack should work. It isn't ideal but hey, it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use auomatic left/right margin if you don't give a value to the width of ul.

If you generate this page with a programming language, you can calculate the width of the UL element having fixed with of LI elements.

So for the second example you can set a width of 796px for UL element obtaining the effect you need.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your `css` you are forcing elements to stay in different positions.

```
eg. #margin-top: -106px; in footer
```

This may lead to different appearances in different browsers. Moreover elements are overflowing.

`eg. elements inside`#wrap`div`.

you can add `overflow: hidden;` to fix that.  Use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and hover over your page and try to fix the `css` issues first.

Comment: Hi Kasun, header and footer are not done by me, the client wants it as it is 'cause there are many pages based on this CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
.select-plan #container ul {
    margin-left: 9em;
}
```

It's not dynamic but it will center 4 containers.